# Compiler Error, ESP8266, NodeMCU (ESP-12E) | BearSSL

Tags: ssl, arduino, nodemcu

I am attempting to compile some code but keep running into the same error. I have done some digging via google, however I have yet to find a solution to the noted error. Any help here would be more than appreciated. Lastly, please forgive my ignorance, this is my first-time using ESP and Arduino.

Issue summary, while compiling the following error is given:

```
    In file included from C:\Users\Muell\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiClientSecure.h:41:0,

                 from C:\Users\Muell\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp5_Hal-Finney-Price-Checker-master.zip\Hal-Finney-Price-Checker-master\main\main.ino:7:

C:\Users\Muell\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.h:262:36: error: expected ')' before '*' token

     WiFiClientSecure(ClientContext *client, const X509List *chain, unsigned cert_issuer_key_type,

                              
C:\Users\Muell\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.h:264:35: error: expected ')' before '*' token

     WiFiClientSecure(ClientContext* client, const X509List *chain, const PrivateKey *sk,

C:\Users\Muell\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.h:38:5: error: 'BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure::~WiFiClientSecure()' marked override, but does not override

     ~WiFiClientSecure() override;

C:\Users\Muell\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.h:43:9: error: 'int BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure::connect(const String&, uint16_t)' marked override, but does not override
     int connect(const String& host, uint16_t port) override;

C:\Users\Muell\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.h:48:12: error: 'size_t BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure::write_P(const char*, size_t)' marked override, but does not override

     size_t write_P(PGM_P buf, size_t size) override;

C:\Users\Muell\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.h:60:12: error: 'size_t BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure::peekBytes(uint8_t*, size_t)' marked override, but does not override

     size_t peekBytes(uint8_t *buffer, size_t length) override;

exit status 1

Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).
```

---

Some of the posts I have read concerning similar problems include:

-https://github.com/arpruss/vectordisplayarduino/issues/2
-https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/2184

Thank you for your help and time,
-JM

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar issue while playing with [Esp8266-lwmqtt](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-iot-arduino/tree/master/examples/Esp8266-lwmqtt). Finally found some additional includes which appeared at the beginning of esp8266_mqtt.h. After reset a sample its compiled successfully.